# NSURLConnection hangs for server which is not available

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using `NSURLConnection initWithRequest` to get some data from a server. This works fine when the server is available. However when the server is not available my app hangs and becomes totally unresponsive for at least 40-50 seconds. I've tried using a `timeoutInterval`, as well as a timer to cancel the request. However my app still hangs.

Whilst my app is hanging, none of the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods have been called. The `onTimeExpire` gets called but doesn't do anything. Once the app becomes responsive again (50 seconds later...), the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` `delegate` methods get called and all is good...

The server is a local server with ip 192.168.x.x which will pull data down to the app only when the server (and csv) file is available.

I thought of doing a simple check before firing off the `NSURLConnection` to see if the server is online first. But can't seem to work out how to do this? Any ideas?

```
-(id) loadCSVByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{

// Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0f];


    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 //for testing..
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(onTimeExpired)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];    

    (void)[self.connection  initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    //THE APP HANGS HERE!!!
    return self;
}

-(void)onTimeExpired
{
    NSLog(@"cancelling connection now!");
    [self.connection cancel];
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: Did you try this both with a simulator and a device? If you press "pause" in the debugger while hanging, where it stops?

Comment: The UI locks up both with the simulator and the device. When I click the pause Thread 1 shows main.m with the 'return' line highlighted:

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([xmlLoaderAppDelegate class]));

Comment: Why are you calling init on the connection and then calling initWithRequest:delegate: on it afterwards? Not sure if it's the reason but it is irregular.

Comment: Yes Wain- you're right, that's my bad. I removed the first init, however the problem still remains.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use AFNetworking for all your client-server communication. It handles the connection asynchronously, so the app never hangs. In addition, it handles timeouts correctly. Do yourself a favor and use existing frameworks.

Comment: Worth looking into the AFNetworking I guess. However the API I'm using should still do the trick, I believe? Without locking my app up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a timeout of 20 but a connection timeout of 30. That means that even if your setup were correct, the timer would fire before the unsuccessful connection fails.

More importantly, you are sending an init message to your `connection` object twice. This does not make sense.

You need instead to create the connection with the request and then `start` it.

```
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                         initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

You then react to the failure of the connection in the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` callback `connection:didFailWithError:` which should fire after the connection times out.

Comment: Thanks. I made the suggested changes. However the main problem still exists- as soon as I call [connection start] my app hangs and is unresponsive. I can't select any other of my tab bar items, for example. Just experimenting-> if I set the timeoutInterval to something small like 10 (and timer bigger), it times out after 10 seconds and calls the connection:didFailWithError: method after 10 seconds. However that locks my app up for 10 seconds. When I make the timer smaller (and timeoutInterval larger) it calls my timeout method and hence [self.connection cancel]; and the app becomes responsive

Comment: It should be asynchronous. Try instaed `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` Something is locking up your UI, but it is not the connection. Do this in `viewDidLoad`, not in the init method.

Comment: I worked it out- as you say it's asynchronous, so it wasn't the connection locking up the app. I was selecting another tab bar item which itself was locking up the app. silly me :( anyway, thanks very much for the help :)